# Error in my javascript for hiding select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two attribute selections and the content of the second one is dependent on the selection of the first. If you select Adult, I want all the Title option to display. If you select Child, I only want Mr or Miss to display.
I wrote a simple javascript to hide the options that are not needed and this almost works correctly.
If I select Child then the unwanted options don't show. If i then change that to Adult, all the options show. But, If i select Adult first, the dropdown breaks apart and leaves me with just a list of the option values.

The javascript I used is

```
$("#attrib-1").change(function () {
var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
switch (id) {
    case "3":
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='6']").wrap('<span/>');
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='7']").wrap('<span/>');
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='9']").wrap('<span/>');
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='10']").wrap('<span/>');
        break;
}

switch (id) {
    case "2":
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='6']").unwrap();
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='7']").unwrap();
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='9']").unwrap();
        $("#attrib-2 option[value='10']").unwrap();
        break;
}

});
```

A fiddle can be found here. http://jsfiddle.net/2t7oj91d/
What can I do to prevent this happening if Adult is the first selection?

Comment: If you select `Adult`, you are unwrapping options, meaning removing their parent which is the select. BTW, only option is valid child of select element, so in case you are selecting child, you are rendering invalid HTML markup. What you see is not what you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`option` elements cannot be wrapped in anything other than a `select`. By unwrapping them you're actually forcing the renderer to remove them from the `select`, which is why your HTML seems to break. Also note that hiding/showing `option` elements is not very well supported across all browsers.

With that in mind you would be better served by enabling/disabling the options. To do this you could add a class to the `option` elements which are only available for the `Adult` option and disable/enable them as required. Try this:

```
$("#attrib-1").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#attrib-2 option.adult").prop('disabled', id == 3);
});
```

```html
<select name="id[2]" id="attrib-2">
    <option value="4">Please Select</option>
    <option value="5">Mr</option>
    <option class="adult" value="6">Mrs</option>
    <option class="adult" value="7">Ms</option>
    <option value="8">Miss</option>
    <option class="adult" value="9">Dr</option>
    <option class="adult" value="10">Prof</option>
</select>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2t7oj91d/1/)

Comment: Couldn't it be just toggled: http://jsfiddle.net/2t7oj91d/2/ ? I guess display none on option is supported by all major browsers (but i could be wrong)

Comment: Whilst I can see this solution fixes the main issue, it does leave the problem where the unwanted options are only greyed out rather than not visible. Is it possible to make them not show at all?

Comment: @A.Wolff I believe that has issues in < IE9. I haven't tested it personally though, so it may well suit the OPs needs.